# Как задать начальное значение для textinput yii2

Tags: php, yii2, form

Есть представление со следующим кодом

```
      <div class="container ">   
      <span class="thisday-year"><strong><?= $newsYear ?></strong></span>
      <div class="form-group col-md-7 thisday-input">
     <?=
     $form->field($model, "news_name[" . $newsYear . "][" . $news->id . "]")->textInput(['placeholder' => ''])->hint('Изменить заголовок статьи...')->label($news->name);
     ?>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Оно берет данные из цикла foreach() и рендерит форму представленную на рисунке 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
что мне нужно указать в настройках field чтобы текст, который содержится в label (на рисунке это "текст label") попал в поле input'a и был редактируемым текстом? Вроде, начального значения для input'a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В `textInput` нужно передать массив с аттрибутом `value`:

```
$form->
field($model, "news_name[" . $newsYear . "][" . $news->id . "]")->
textInput(['placeholder' => '', 'value'=>'Тут редактируемый текст'])->
hint('Изменить заголовок статьи...')->label($news->name);
```

Comment: А как правильно туда поставить переменную? Я делаю вот так
'value'=> "."$news->name"."
и получаю "не ожидалось variable "$news" после string
UPD разобрался)

->textInput(['placeholder' => '', 'value'=> $news->name ])

Answer (score 1):

Главная проблема в том, что ты используешь в названии поля `"news_name[" . $newsYear . "][" . $news->id . "]"`. Используй простые названия полей. Если тебе нужно, чтобы в поле был массив, разбивай на несколько полей.

При условии, что поле у тебя будет называться `news`:

```
$form->field($model, "news")->textInput(['value' => $model->news ?? 'Значение по умолчанию']);
```

Или, например, если тебе нужно новое поле при создании модели:

```
 if ($model->isNewRecord){
     $model->news = 'Значение по умолчанию'
 }
 $form->field($model, "news")->textInput();
```

И жить становится проще и веселей.